Help me identify a capacitor marked 335K MPS 450
Capacitor marking is 335K MPS 450.

Help me to identify this capacitor.


335 = 33 x 105 pF = 3.3 μF

K indicates  the tolerance, 10% (F: 1%, J: 5%, K: 10%, M: 20%)

450 indicates the 450V voltage rating.

It's a film capacitor and must be either metallised polyester or metallised polypropylene.

Pitch (distance between the pins) needs to be measured. Difficult to guess from here. Can be anything between 15mm and 22.5mm, I don't know but you measure.

I can't recognise the manufacturer logo.


With these information you can find an equivalent from well-known retailers such as Digikey or Mouser.
